# Range out of order in character class - regex

Tags: javascript, regex, encoding

I have the following set of code

```
var nameStartChar = /[A-Z_a-z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\u00F8-\u02FF\u0370-\u037D\u037F-\u1FFF\u200C-\u200D\u2070-\u218F\u2C00-\u2FEF\u3001-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFFD]///\u10000-\uEFFFF
var nameChar = new RegExp("[\\-\\.0-9"+nameStartChar.source.slice(1,-1)+"\u00B7\u0300-\u036F\\ux203F-\u2040]");
var tagNamePattern = new RegExp('^'+nameStartChar.source+nameChar.source+'*(?:\:'+nameStartChar.source+nameChar.source+'*)?$');
```

It throws the following error:

```
sqmtest I/JS: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[\-\.0-9A-Z_a-z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\u00F8-\u02FF\u0370-\u037D\u037F-\u1FFF\u200C-\u200D\u2070-\u218F\u2C00-\u2FEF\u3001-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFFD????-??\ux203F-???]/: Range out of order in character class
at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
at RegExp (<anonymous>)
at Object.$$_sax (http://com.hashcube.sqtest/modules/devkit-core/src/clientapi/native/dom/sax.js:1:5952)
at I (none:615:5092)
at z (none:615:6690)
at Object.jsio (none:615:7357)
at Object.$$_dom_parser (http://com.hashcube.sqtest/modules/devkit-core/src/clientapi/native/dom/dom_parser.js:1:3511)
at I (none:615:5092)
at z (none:615:6690)
at Object.jsio (none:615:7357)
at Object.$$_dom_DOMParser (http://com.hashcube.sqtest/modules/devkit-core/src/clientapi/native/dom/DOMParser.js:1:66)
at I (none:615:5092)
at z (none:615:6690)
at Object.jsio (none:615:7357)
at Object.$$_common.exports.install (http://com.hashcube.sqtest/modules/devkit-core/src/clientapi
```

The full code is here -> https://github.com/hashcube/devkit-core/blob/hc/src/clientapi/native/dom/sax.js

Any idea why the regex could be failing.
I have not confirmed this, but looks like minification could be causing an issue.

Any thoughts suggestions would help me. I can provide more details if needed

**EDIT**

I have more information. I looked at the minifed code for both these lines from 2 machines(1 machine where I get this error and another where I don't get the error). It looks like an encoding issue to me. Any help would be appreciated

Machine with Error

```
var nameStartChar=/[A-Z_a-z\\xC0-\\xD6\\xD8-\\xF6\\u00F8-\\u02FF\\u0370-\\u037D\\u037F-\\u1FFF\\u200C-\\u200D\\u2070-\\u218F\\u2C00-\\u2FEF\\u3001-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFFD]/,
  nameChar=RegExp("[\\\\-\\\\.0-9"+nameStartChar.source.slice(1,-1)+"????-??\\\\ux203F-???]"),
  tagNamePattern=RegExp("^"+nameStartChar.source+nameChar.source+"*(?::"+nameStartChar.source+nameChar.source+"*)?$"),S_TAG=0,S_ATTR=1,S_ATTR_S=2,S_EQ=3,S_V=4,S_E=5,S_S=6,S_C=7;
```

Machine without error

```
var nameStartChar=/[A-Z_a-z\\xC0-\\xD6\\xD8-\\xF6\\u00F8-\\u02FF\\u0370-\\u037D\\u037F-\\u1FFF\\u200C-\\u200D\\u2070-\\u218F\\u2C00-\\u2FEF\\u3001-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFFD]/,
  nameChar=RegExp("[\\\\-\\\\.0-9"+nameStartChar.source.slice(1,-1)+"·�~@-ͯ\\\\ux203F-�~A~@]"),]"),A~@
  tagNamePattern=RegExp("^0-9"+nameStartChar.sou+nameChar.source+"*(?::"+nameStartChar.source+nameChar.source+"*)?$"),S_TAG=0,S_ATTR=1,S_ATTR_S=2,S_EEouQ=3,S_V=4,S_E=5,S_S=6,S_C=7;
```

Comment: What is the intention of `\uFDF0-\uFFFD????-??\ux203F-???` ?

Comment: It just works as it is, maybe you'r right about minification.

Comment: @ymutlu Why do you think minification might cause an issue ?

Comment: @AlexK. I really don't know. It is a framework we use and I have recently started encountering this. Will try to understand this better

Comment: Generally when you have a pattern that long, there is either a much simpler solution or you just shouldn't be using regex.

Comment: @ymutlu and others. I've edited the question with more info. Looks like an encoding issue to me. Your thoughts?

Comment: @AlexK. The original code during minifcation gets converted to `\uFDF0-\uFFFD????-??\ux203F-???`. I'm guessing it is an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are providing ranges that are not really range for Regex like;

```
????-??\\\\ux203F-??? => ????-??\\ux203F-???
```

`\\ux203F-???` This is not a range for regex and causes the problem. Rest seems like correct.

Regex accept this one `·�~@-ͯ\\\\ux203F-�~A~@`, you can use this if it works for you.

Check [Character ranges](https://regexone.com/lesson/character_ranges) link, this might help you restructure your regex.

PS: "Machine without error" returns "Unexpected token ]"

Comment: We found the issue. It was because of the following environment variable LANG=C